# Create "Many to Many" relationship between multiple tables with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, typescript, sequelize.js

I have an already existing schema in MSSQL (image below),
I have a searches table, each search is made up of some metadata and 3 types of filters (can be multiple of each for each search), and I have a "Many to Many" table to connect all types of filters to the search.
I'd like to use Sequelize to query my searches and get the filters for each, but I couldn't find any way to connect the multiple filters to my search table to model using the connecting table (filters)

[image: DB Design]

Searches: contains metadata of the search and the search id.
Filters: contains search id and matches it to filter using filter id and filter type (enum: "range","datetime","exact").
Range filter, datetime filters, exact filters: the filter itself and it's info.

In case it's not possible to query them all together, I thought it might be a possible (but less efficient maybe) to create a view over these tables and create a model for it in Sequelize, but I'm not sure I could do that as well.

Is it possible to model the way I want? And if it is, how can i create this connections?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sequelize when you have other attributes other than foreign keys in the middle table, you'll have to define its model too.
According to above schema, you'll have to have model of all the tables including the middle one (filters).
**Assign associations in this way:**

```
//associations from search model
SearchesModel.belongsToMany(RangesFiltersModel, {through: FiltersModel, foriegnKey: 'filter_search_id', otherKey: 'filter_id'});
SearchesModel.belongsToMany(ExactFiltersModel, {through: FiltersModel, foriegnKey: 'filter_search_id', otherKey: 'filter_id'});
SearchesModel.belongsToMany(DatetimeFiltersModel, {through: FiltersModel, foriegnKey: 'filter_search_id', otherKey: 'filter_id'});

//associations from filters
RangesFilterModel.belongsToMany(SearchesModel, {through: FiltersModel, foreignKey: 'filter_id', otherKey: 'filter_search_id'});
ExactFilterModel.belongsToMany(SearchesModel, {through: FiltersModel, foreignKey: 'filter_id', otherKey: 'filter_search_id'});
DatetimeFilterModel.belongsToMany(SearchesModel, {through: FiltersModel, foreignKey: 'filter_id', otherKey: 'filter_search_id'});
```

Now, suppose I have a search object:

```
search.getRangesFilterModels({through: {filterType: 'range'}});
search.getDatetimeFilterModels({through: {filterType: 'datetime'}});
search.getExactFilterModels({through: {filterType: 'exact'}});
```

When you want to retrieve all search objects where each object contains all associated filters, you can query this way:

```
SearchesModel.findAll({
    include: [{
        ExactFilterModel,
        through: {filterType: 'exact'}
    }, {
        DatetimeFilterModel,
        through: {filterType: 'datetime'}
    }, {
        RangesFilterModel,
        through: {filterType: 'range'}
    }]
});
```

P.S. The exact code might not work, but the concept is same. Hope this would help you. For more information, follow the link in the reference
Reference: [Sequelize Associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html)

Comment: Worked, almost perfectly! required some changes to fit (mostly methods signatures adjustments), but worked really good, and made the joins correctly

Answer (score 0):

[image]

May be you could use above design with two table one is searches and other is filter which refer searches, with adding cases in your filters based on filter type.

Example:-

case when type is exact then pick only key_exactvalue column.

case when type is range(int/date) then pick respective cast/convert(min_range & Max_range) with range_datatype

**Solution 2:-**

```
create view VW_Filters as 

select filter_id,'Range' as filter_type,....[other columns]
from ranges_filters

union

select filter_id,'Exact' as filter_type,....[other columns]
from ranges_filters


union

select filter_id,'Datetime' as filter_type,....[other columns]
from ranges_filters
```

Then you need to create a view on top of filter tables and then join with your main filter table on filter_id and filter_type to fetch required filters for search criteria.

Comment: While valid and a great solution, my problem lies in the fact that the tables already exists, that allows me to create that design by modeling a view, and not model an existing table

Comment: Check out my other solution in answer section.